# How to override the Devise Passwords Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How to override the Devise Passwords Controller:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

I want to do the following:

1. downcase all emails submitted for password reset. All the emails in the DB as lowercase. If a user tried to reset a valid email with any characters uppercase, the reset fails to find a user. And devise doesn't even give a error message saying no user found
2. If no user is found in def create, I want to add a flash that says, no user found, did you enter the right email?

How can I accomplish the 2 items above? I believe that required overriding the devise password controller. How do I do that? Or if you have a better solution that's even cleaner, I would like to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the devise initializer has a option to make any field case insensitive:

`config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]`

If I remember correctly it was added in the newer version and if you don't see some related comments in you initializer then you should upgrade your devise gem using `bundle upgrade devise`. I am using version 1.3.3.
And this version also shows an error "Email not found" if an invalid email is entered.

If you not getting the error message add `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` to your view. You can customize the error messages by editing `config/locales/devise.en.yml`

Comment: It was added in 1.2rc: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc   Therefore it should work for you. Try adding `config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]` to the devise.rb initializer.

Comment: :) And if you are still not getting the error message add `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` to your view. You can customize the error messages by editing config/locales/devise.en.yml